# Как убрать кнопку на панели визуального редактора CKeditor

Tags: jquery, javascript, редактор

Как в [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) Basic на панельке убрать кнопку "О CKeditor"? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.cke_button_about{
  display: none;
}
```

разработчика огорчает ваше желание сделать это.

Comment: Его это не должно колыхать продукт ОпенСоирс и лицензия ГНУ... :)

Comment: Ну, у него есть и платные фишки(прикольный менеджер файлов), путь к которым лежит через любовь к халявному редактору

Answer (score 0):

Да можно просто в цсс написать

```
#cke_83 {
  display:none
}
```

Сепаратор можно убрать таким же макаром.

можно залезть в код и найти место где генерируется эта кнопка и удалить ее

Answer (score 0):

```
build-config.js   ->
-> plugins : {
        'a11yhelp' : 1,
        'about' : 0,

= **Выставить 0**, пересобрать
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в config.js:

```
config.removeButtons = 'About';
```

Или там же удалить из **config.toolbarGroups**, если есть:

```
{ name: 'about' }
```